# The downloads in Windows 10 are waiting for a while

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

The downloads are waiting for a while (3min-20min) no matter which browser you are using (Firefox, Opera, Chrome)

After the file is downloaded 100% it can not be opened for a while.

- In the same network there is another PC with Ubuntu(So the network is ok)
- Windows 10 original and with full updates
- Windows defenser disabled
- I don't have Antivirus
- Windows 10 reinstalled 3 times, each one with a differente HD/SSD new
- Tested with different browsers: Chrome, Firefox, Opera

[image]

Comment: check your antivirus settings

Comment: Came here to say this. Usually this is waiting for an antivirus program to scan the file

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: What security software do you have installed?

Comment: neither. I dont have any security software, its a windows 10 fresh installation

Comment: Why is Windows Defender disabled?

Comment: To test if that was the problem, tested with WD on and off, still the problem exists.